# Iterate over rows and update each of them

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL database i have `users` table which contains `name` field. I want to iterate over each rows in `users` table and update it name to some random string. How can I do this in PostgreSQL

Comment: `update users set name = ...`?

Comment: Are you trying to create obfuscated test data from your live system?  If so, this is a very bad idea and you should stop right now.

Comment: I'm only trying to learn new thing in postgresql... This will not be used on live system...

Comment: @iamdave: what's so bad about that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Data protection is a potentially **huge** problem and it takes very little to identify an individual.  Once you have gone to the trouble of obfuscating all names, personal dates, addresses, NI/SS Numbers, email addresses, other info like credit card details, etc you will have spent more effort than simply generating it from scratch, but will still run the risk of having missed something.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Especially when the list of options available to help you do such a task is [vast](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+data+generator).

Comment: @iamdave That's opinionated, and it has nothing to do with the question. I personally think that creating good test data artificially is much harder than obfuscating production data well.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users
SET name =  md5(random()::text);
```

Comment: I'm looking for solution using a loop. Inside this loop I will have some conditional logic.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański: why do you think you need a loop? You did not specify any "conditional logic" in your question. You just stated that you need a random string.

Comment: you can loop if you have UK, but usually `CASE WHEN` inside `update` is enough for simple splits logic